# Access Form controls from static class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, static-members

I have a Form1 with lots of controls and I need to access/edit control values from another static class. Since I have lots of controls on the form, it takes some time to define set and get from every single of them. I am wondering if there is any way that I can define an instance of the Form1 within the static class so that I can have access to all controls of Form1 in this class?

Here is the structure of the static class:

```
public static class Glob
{
    public static int int1;

    public static int Func1()
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

I am using static class with static methods and variables as I need to be able to easily access its variables and methods from any other form and class. This way I do not need to define an instance of the class every single time I need to call them. Also, by help of static class, I can share variables between classes and forms.

Comment: Seems like you want to have a composite root that you inject into those other forms and classes. And probably more than one. Look into the Single Responsibility Principle and Dependency Injection.

Comment: Are partial classes better than static classes for this matter? I defined partial classes before. It worked, but I had to change the name of all of the classes to classname.designer.cs in order to get rid of the form.

Comment: @GrantWinney: Are partial classes better than static classes for this matter? I defined partial classes before. It worked, but I had to change the name of all of the classes to classname.designer.cs in order to get rid of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare in the static form:

```
private static MyformType myform;

public static void setmyform(MyformType myform1)
{
  myform=myform1;
}
```

although, that concept generally isn't so good, maybe better way would be passing your form as argument to functions called in the static class, and make your contorl which should be accesed public, by chanign acces modifier in propertis box of the form

```
public static void EgClearText(Textbox tb)
{
  tb.Text="";
}
public static void DoSomethingElseWithTheForm(MyformType myform)
{
  myform.someOtherContol.Visible=false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply singleton pattern to your form. Note that *Instance* will return reference to last created instance of MyForm, so you shouldn't have more than one instance of MyForm out there.

Backing field:

```
    private static MyForm _instance
```

Singleton accessor:

```
    public static MyForm Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }
```

Once you beging using the class, you can assign its reference to the backing field

```
    public MyForm()
    {
        _instance = this;
    }
```

As a side note; if you have a choice of technologies, check out WPF. It has [bindings](http://wpftutorial.net/Databinding.html) to programmatically get and set values of UI controls at

Comment: @Tetsujin no Oni singleton pattern works with WinForms. WPF is a suggestion.

Comment: Certainly, but since the question specified winforms, talking about WPF is headed for "not an answer" territory...